# Para que serve o Prevayler?

Tags: java, objetos

Estou estudando `Prevayler` na faculdade, porém não sei a real utilidade, nem o por que usar, procurando na internet achei várias discussões porém nada que explicasse de fato para que ele serve. Seria pra armazenar em memória dados para persistir todos de uma vez por meio de um comando? Ou falei asneira rsrs?

Obrigado a comunidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma biblioteca de Persistência de dados diferente das convencionais.

Primeiro, a persistência de dados, é uma forma de guardar as informações, para poder usa-las posteriormente, seja ela em bancos de dados, ou logs, como é o caso do Prevayler.

O Legal dele é que ele faz a persistência por registros e serializa objetos em disco, ele não é relacional como outras bibliotecas de persistência, ou seja, ele não vai criar bases e tabelas, para armazenar essas informações.

A ideia é interessante, e optaria por usa-lo em pequenos projetos, ou em casos em que a informação é temporária.